# Popover is shown null

Tags: ios, ipad, popover

I'm trying to show a popover with a title, creating a root view controller and instantiating it with my viewController. But, when I show the popover, the content is not shown. Here is the code:

```
        UIViewController *popContentViewController = [[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"videosTutoriais"] init];
    UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popContentViewController];
    _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
    _popover.delegate = self;

    [popContentViewController release];
    [controller release];

    //dados.myPopoverController = popOverController;
    [[self popover] presentPopoverFromRect:ancora.bounds inView:ancora permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Just to be more specific, the title of popover appears normally, but the content doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looked like this:

```
sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *controller = [[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navTutorial"] init];
    _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];

    [[self popover] presentPopoverFromRect:ancora.bounds inView:ancora permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [controller release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just double check that popContentViewController is not nil. You have the identifier @"videosTutoriais" which looks like it might be a scanning error.

Comment: Nope! The popContentViewController is not nil. It's loading correctly my view controller...

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you are releasing the controller before you display in on the screen. Try releasing it after or in the dealloc method. If you are unsure about memory management. I suggest you try ARC instead to avoid silly errors and mistakes such as this.

Comment: From my understanding, you are using the navigation controller simply for the navigation bar on the top to add a title? Because your problem might originate from the UINavigationController, try displaying the root controller, without the navigation

Comment: yep! I'm doing this for the title. I've tried to do as you said, but still not working...

Comment: I got it!! Instead instatiating the view controller, I instantiated directly the navigation controller that I've created on storyboard. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: well another obvious question, does the sb or storyboard object related to your actual storyboard that contains the view controller? and does that view controller have the identifier "videoTutorials"?

Comment: Yep! The storyboard contain the view controller and it has this identifier. Now it's working perfectly with the title and content.

Comment: so what was the final issue?